# Why case: always requires constant expression while if() doesn't?

Tags: c, if-statement, switch-statement

May be possible duplicate but couldn't have found the same.

Suppose I have following `C` code :

```
int a;
printf("Enter number :");
scanf("%d",&a);  // suppose entered only an integer
                // ignoring return value of scanf()
```

I got a case to check whether `a` is `zero` or `non-zero`.

```
if(a)
  printf("%d is non-zero",a);
else
  printf("%d is zero",a);
```

Everything is fine using `if-else` and I also know the other variations of `if-else` to achieve this . But problem comes with the `switch-case` as it says that we can implement everything in `switch-case` which we can do in `if-else`. But the following code fails.

```
switch(a)
{
 case a:
       printf("%d is non-zero",a);
       break;
 default:
       printf("%d is zero",a);
       break;
}
```

Also I know to reverse the case in the above code like this below will work and I will have my answer.

```
switch(a)
{
case 0:
    printf("%d is zero",a);
    break;
default :
    printf("%d is non-zero",a);
    break;
}
```

But the question is, **Why** ? Why `if(a)` is valid while `case a:` is not ? Is `switch-case` a compile time operation and `if()` run-time ?

Comment: Jump tables? With constant expressions, the switch can possibly be compiled into a jump table.

Comment: @DanielFischer :You got my point.. yes I want implementation. How if's and case are implemented so that one needs only constant expression and other not

Comment: why the constant expression needed in case why not `a` because at that point `a` is having some value.I know there are lot many constraints that case `string` and `floats` are also not valid ... it means there must be something related to integers only and so a is integer here , then why the constant expression ?.

Comment: @DanielFischer - Do you really think with only two possibilities a compiler would create a jump table? Sure if there were a number of consecutively incrementing cases, but with only one? I'd think it would still just be a single compare and branch.

Comment: @Mike No, of course not. With only two cases, it will create an `if`. But allowing variables in `switch` statements with fewer than 16 branches, and only constant expressions for large ones would be madness. However, I have no idea whether jump tables entered the consideration when it was decided that `case`s should only be constant expressions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason is that `switch` cases can be implemented as jump tables (typically using unconditional branch instructions). So they have to be resolved at compile time.

This makes them faster than `if`s so it is better to use them when possible.

Comment: Not "are", only "can sometimes be", AFAIK.

Answer (score 2):

Case expressions must be constants. `a` is a variable, so it is not allowed. `0` is a constant, so that's fine. Only allowing constant expressions means that it is easier for the compiler to optimize the code.

The expression for the condition of an if statement has no such constraint.

Comment: Because that's what the specification says.

Comment: that's fine... but please make me understand, one needs constant while other is just fine .I want implementation of it or any link so that I can get it from there

Comment: @MarkByers I think he is interested in the rationale of such choice and this answer does not answer the question.

Comment: @oauh: "Only allowing constant expressions means that it is easier for the compiler to optimize the code." answers the question IMHO.

Comment: I was more answering your first comment but I agree your point makes an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Beyond the compile-time/jump-table problem, `if` and `switch` are not the same and even if `case` would accept a variable those two codes wouldn't have the same behavior. `if` body is evaluated if and only if the condition expression results in a non-zero value, while a `case` is entered if and only if the controlling expression and the label have the same value.

There is a *big* difference between `if-then-else` and `switch` statements, remember that `break`s are not mandatory and execution falls through all the `case`s if nothing stops it. This behavior is really similar to a jump table, since inside a `switch` execution simply jump somewhere and goes on until it finds a `break`. However this use is rare, but it could be useful and easier to do than the `if-then-else` version.

The standard requires labels to be compile-time constants, and as other people already say, the idea behind it is a jump table for performance. Even if it's not mandatory (the C standard needs to be flexible), C99 rationale document seems to confirm this:

> Case ranges of the form, lo .. hi, were seriously considered, but ultimately not adopted in the Standard on the grounds that it added no new capability, just a problematic coding convenience. The construct seems to promise more than it could be mandated to deliver:
>
> - A great deal of code or **jump table** space might be generated for an innocent-looking case range such as 0 .. 65535.
> - The range 'A' .. 'Z' would specify all the integers between the character code for
>   “upper-case-A” and that for “upper-case-Z”. In some common character sets this range
>   would include non-alphabetic characters, and in others it might not include all the
>   alphabetic characters, especially in non-English character sets.

[Wikipedia has an article about jump tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_table).

Comment: why the constant expression needed in case why not `a` because at that point a is having some value.I know there are lot many constraints that case string and floats are also not valid ... it means there must be something related to integers only and so `a` is integer here , then why the constant expression ?..

Comment: @Omkant other people already said something about this, I added a quote in my question

Comment: @Omkant Yes, we have to jump anyway if we want to move somewhere in the code, but if the range of the cases is small then a compiler could generate an array of addresses (one for each `case`) and put the address of the code of the `case X:` at the index `X` of the array. This way the code could do something that ideally would look like `goto address[controlExpression]`, in constant time and without any comparison. If the range is big and element are sparse, or there are negative values and things like that, compiler could implement hashing or search, but that could be non-trivial.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, it's the way the language was defined.

If you have

```
int x, y, z;
int a;
... some code calculates x, y, z and a ... 
switch(a)
{
   case x:
      .. do stuff here ... 
      break;
   case y:
      .. some more stuff ...
      break;
   case z:
     ... another bit of code .... 
      break;
}
```

the compiler can not figure out beforehand, at time of compilation where a should go if it's 1, 2, 3, 99, 465 or 5113212. So the code here is no more efficient than if we did

```
if (a == x) ... do stuff here ... 
else if (a == y) ... some more stuff
else if (a == z) ... another bit of code
```

Further, what if x and y are the same value. Do we want BOTH do stuff and some more stuff to be executed, or just the one - and which one, the first or the second. What if the compiler re-orders the compares so that they are in a different order, because it's more efficient?

Switch is mainly intended for when you have a lot of choices of something, but each choice is known when you build the code. If that's not the case, you need something else.

Comment: Compilers don't reorder the code if it could make a difference (and if it's standard compliant), that would be a compiler bug.

Answer (score 1):

Additional Information want to share [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch_statement)

`If the range of input values is identifiably 'small' and has only a few gaps, some 
compilers that incorporate an optimizer may actually implement the switch statement as 
a jump table or an array of indexed function pointers instead of a lengthy series of 
conditional instructions. This allows the switch statement to determine instantly what 
branch to execute without having to go through a list of comparisons.`

Answer (score 1):

It's a design decision by the creators of the language. *IF* case labels are constant, the compiler can optimize some cases by using a jump table. If they are not, the code will be equivalent to the multi-way if statement anyway, and the potential improvement goes away.

There is no problem defining a switch statement with variable case labels, or even different conditions for each branch, it is just that the designers of C didn't do that. Likely because they didn't see that as an advantage for the code they were writing.

The construct exists in other languages, like the COBOL I sometimes use. There it is not unusual to have a degenerated version like:

```
EVALUATE TRUE
WHEN x IS EQUAL TO 7
  Do something

WHEN y IS LESS THAN 12 
  Do something else

WHEN z
  Do yet another thing

END-EVALUATE
```

Here we have the `if-else if-else` chain masked as a switch (EVALUATE), which works by evaluating the conditions *in order* until it matches the first value.

In C the designers didn't want this, because it offers absolutely no performance advantage over the chained if-statements. On the other hand, if we require that all the conditions are constants...